# Trying to make a macro with AutoHotkey and need assistance

Tags: script, macros, autohotkey

I have been trying to write an AutoHotkey script that renames my game's instance and continues to send keystrokes to the game while I use my mouse and keyboard in a different window.

The thing I've been stuck on recently in the script is where it opens the in-game chat by sending Enter then pastes some text and sends the message, again by sending Enter. I do it with a `.ini` file so the text can be saved and I don't know if this is making it harder or not.

When ever it does work it doesnt work fully because it send the text to other things like when i tab out instead of going to the games chat

Was wondering if anyone could help me with my issues

Code for sending:

```
F1:: ; Start spam F1
Gui, Submit, nohide
toggle=1
While toggle
{
    Sleep, 1000
    ControlSend,, {enter}, TradeSpamAcc
    Sleep, 200
    ControlFocus,, TradeSpamAcc
    Sleep, 200
    SendInput, %TextEdit% ; from ini file
    Sleep, 200
    ControlSend,, {enter}, TradeSpamAcc
    Sleep, 12000
}
return
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.